# can nagareru or utsukushi be name?

Tags: names

I want to know if Nagareru or ustukushi can be name. Cuz i read article talk about japanese name cannot be certain things like this. Just want to know, can nagareru be name. I names my character this based off the meaning, to flow.
Edit: Sorry, major error. I spell cat, I meant character.

Comment: sorry for poor english

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly it is you are asking? Do you want to know if these can be names for people in Japanese? Do you want to know if Japanese people would give these as names to cats?

Comment: I want to know if I can use nagareru as a name. For my character.

Comment: did nots mean a cat. This was error

Answer (score 2):

流れる(nagareru) is a verb and 美しい(utsukushii) an adjective. Both of these words are not used for names, but their kanji characters are. for example 流 can be read as haru and have the meaning of flow/stream. same goes for the character 美 which is often used for a girls name.

but in the end it is all up to you how you want to name your character, and if you like nagareru then you should stick with that name. to make it a noun instead of verd make it nagare which means flow.

Comment: So they are not used as names, but can be?

Comment: The characters can be used within a name with different readings, the verb themselves aren't used for names. It is not a matter of being able to. Look at Kanye west naming his son North. We live in a time where almost everything can be a name. if you want a name with the character try 愛流(airu). it consists of the character for love(愛) and flow(流). it is a popular name for Japanese girls

Comment: `愛流(airu) ... is a popular name for Japanese girls` <- まさか 　http://dqname.jp/index.php?md=view&c=aa1611 / https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1427340954

Comment: キラキラネームとか最近結構人気になっています。僕もあまり好きじゃないのですが、傾向は傾向です。仕方ないでしょう。